Can an Ansible playbook be run concurrently with itself, with different inventory files for each of runs?
I want to use a common deployment box with ansible in it, and connectivity to all my various environments, which are in dozens. Jenkins jobs will invoke the ansible playbooks (common for all environs) after generating inventory files and copying them over (assume they will have unique names).
The inventory files are separate but they may contain the same variable names. My gumption tells me it is not an issue as they will be run in different process spaces. But I would appreciate it if someone can shine a light on this scheme to say if it is a good way or if I should take other approach which is closer to industry standard
First, will ansible run OK in this scenario? Second, is this a common scenario, or are there other approaches regarded as the best practices?

It will work just fine, but you should make sure that any logs go to separate files/outputs so you don't mix up the different runs.
This is assuming that you don't have any of the same machines in different inventories. Overlapping inventories would make me more nervous.

This should work, considering the same that has been highlighted in Richard's answer.
One thing I would add is that you can run an Ansible playbook itself with multiple inventories:
ansible-playbook playbook.yml \
  --inventory one.yml \
  --inventory two.yml \
  ...

ansible-playbook playbook.yml --inventory one.yml,two.yml,...

export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=one.yml,two.yml,...
ansible-playbook playbook.yml

This means, that if you don't have the intersections between the hosts and groups, you may be fine to do everything at once.
